# Pre-supplying answer to linux program

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

When I run the following command:

`yiic webapp main /home/david123/domains/david123.servehttp.com/public_html/main`

It waits for my answer:

```
Create a Web application under '/home/david123/domains/david123.servehttp.com/public_html/main'? [Yes|No]
```

Rather than entering Yes/No each time I run this command, I would like to pre-supply the answer to the command. What should I append to my original command?

`yiic webapp main /home/david123/domains/david123.servehttp.com/public_html/main`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should prepend an invocation of `yes`.

```
yes Yes | yiic webapp main /home/david123/domains/david123.servehttp.com/public_html/main
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It has solved my problem. The program only asks me one question so I only need a single yes, right?

Comment: The `yes` command will keep supplying yesses whether the program needs them or not.

Comment: Sounds like some former coworkers.

Comment: @David Schwartz I didn't know there exists such an interesting command. Thanks a lot for your information.